# I am looking for multiple percentage change calculator with same codes. Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I developed a percentage change calculator with jquery. It is working file. But problem is, I can't make multiple calculator with same jquery codes. Now each calculator need special codes and class for it. Is it possible muliple calculator without adding any extra codes ? Codepen preview : https://codepen.io/toolsim/pen/ZEoYbgY . Please help me...

```js
$(document).on("change keyup blur live", ".ChangeCalulator", function() { // For:- = Topper To Current %
  ///////////////////
  var first = Number($('.From101').val()); // = Topper Price
  var second = Number($('.To101').val()); // = Current Price
  var minus = second - first; // 2000 - 1000 = {1000 = minus}
  var divide = (minus / first); // 1000 / 1000 = 1
  var multiply = divide * 100; // 1 * 100 = 100%
  $('.Result101').val(Number(multiply).toFixed(2)); // = Topper to Current %
  ///////////////////////
  var first = Number($('.From102').val()); // = Topper Price
  var second = Number($('.To102').val()); // = Current Price
  var minus = second - first; // 2000 - 1000 = {1000 = minus}
  var divide = (minus / first); // 1000 / 1000 = 1
  var multiply = divide * 100; // 1 * 100 = 100%
  $('.Result102').val(Number(multiply).toFixed(2)); // = Topper to Current %
});
/////////////////////////
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="ChangeCalulator From101" value="">
<input type="text" class="To101" value="25000">
<input type="text" class="Result101" value="">
<br><br>
<input type="text" class="ChangeCalulator From102" value="">
<input type="text" class="To102" value="25000">
<input type="text" class="Result102" value="">
<br><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, treat each one individually, by wrapping it inside a container `.section`. Use an event handler on each of the required inputs, use `input` event, then by finding parent element you can find other elements in same "line".

```js
var func_change = function() {
  var input = this;
  var parent = this.closest(".section")

  var first = Number(parent.querySelector('.From101').value);
  var second = Number(parent.querySelector('.To101').value);
  var minus = second - first;
  var divide = (minus / first);
  var multiply = divide * 100;
  parent.querySelector('.Result101').value = (Number(multiply).toFixed(2));

};

document.querySelectorAll(".ChangeCalulator").forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("input", func_change);
});

// trigger "remotely"
func_change.call (document.querySelector('.From101'))
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <input type="text" class="ChangeCalulator From101" value="">
  <input type="text" class="ChangeCalulator To101" value="25000">
  <input type="text" class="Result101" value="">
</div>
<br>
<div class="section">
  <input type="text" class="ChangeCalulator From101" value="">
  <input type="text" class="ChangeCalulator To101" value="25000">
  <input type="text" class="Result101" value="">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi .. When I type in second input, <input type="text" class="To101" value=""> not working.

Comment: Add class `ChangeCalulator` to it as well

Comment: 1 more help please.. Percentage is not changing automatically when I add in my Bitcoin Live price code. Please make it as automatically changing.. Codepen URL : https://codepen.io/toolsim/pen/ZEoYbgY

Comment: just somehow trigger the event listener function (call it `func_change`) manually whenever you change the input. like `func_change.call(input_elem)`

Comment: I dont understand.. Full code please..

Comment: I've updated my answer already, call `func_change()` whenever an element changes. Pass that element as "context" (to be the `this`) like this `func_change.call(element)`

Comment: Please check this link: https://codepen.io/toolsim/pen/ZEoYbgY Result is showing **Infinity** I need to type in To101 to show result.. Not automatic

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247778/discussion-between-vivek-vivi-and-it-goldman).

Comment: Simply add `func_change.call(stockPriceInput)` before end of `onmessage`

Comment: I added a new code for copy live Bitcoin price from  `<input type="text" id="btc-price" class="To101 ChangeCalulator copyfrom" >`<!-- copyfrom --> To   `<input type="text" class="ChangeCalulator From101 pasted" value="1000">`<!-- pasted -->
It is working only when I type in `<input>`. Can you make it as automatically ?
Please check this link : codepen.io/toolsim/pen/ZEoYbgY . I think it is a simple task for you..

Comment: Live demo : https://codepen.io/toolsim/pen/ZEoYbgY

Comment: Do you know answer of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73630166/tablesorter-is-not-sorting-calculation-result-columns-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code:

For HTML:

```
<div class="section">
  <input type="text" class="ChangeCalulator From101" value="">
  <input type="text" class="To101" value="25000">
  <input type="text" class="Result101" value="">
</div>
<br>
<div class="section">
  <input type="text" class="ChangeCalulator From101" value="">
  <input type="text" class="To101" value="25000">
  <input type="text" class="Result101" value="">
</div>
```

For Jquery:

```
$(document).on("change keyup blur live", ".ChangeCalulator", function() {// For:- = Topper To Current %
  let formContainer = $(this).closest('.section')

  var first = Number($(formContainer).find('.From101').val()); // = Topper Price
  var second = Number($(formContainer).find('.To101').val()); // = Current Price
  var minus = second - first; // 2000 - 1000 = {1000 = minus}
  var divide = (minus / first); // 1000 / 1000 = 1
  var multiply = divide * 100; // 1 * 100 = 100%
  $(formContainer).find('.Result101').val(Number(multiply).toFixed(2)); 

});
```

Comment: Do you know answer of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73630166/tablesorter-is-not-sorting-calculation-result-columns-jquery-javascript